# Modify permalink of CPT archive to support two taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

there are hundreds of questions like these but some outdated and some are just bloated with code, hope I can make things simple.

**CPT Slug:** resources
**Taxonomy Slug:** language
**Taxonomy Slug:** program

I have the template that displays the archive of resources at:

`localhost/resources`

What I would like to achieve is to filter the archive of resources based on the URL structure:

`localhost/resources/language/program`

For example:

`localhost/resources/afrikaans/quit4baby`

Which would display all resources that have the language taxonomy of afrikaans and the program taxonomy of quit4baby.

I already have the query for filtering things, I just cannot figure out what is the best way to convert that permalink structure into query args.

The first function I wrote is called as an action from init:

```php
    public static function rewrite_rules() {
        add_rewrite_rule(
            'resources/([^/]*)',
            home_url( 'resources/?language=$1' ),
            'top'
        );
    }
```

The second function is called from the `query_vars` filter:

```php
    public static function register_custom_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
        $query_vars[] = 'language';
        return $query_vars;
    }
```

I was hoping that after doing this, my template would be able to see if the language query var was set (and eventually the program, but I'm taking baby steps).

But when I access:

`http://localhost/resources/afrikaans`

It loads the single resource that has been marked with the Afrikaans taxonomy, this happens with or without my code above.

Is this the best way to achieve this? If so, why isn't the path structure rewritten and caught by the archive page for me to filter things appropriately?

Thank you so much for taking the time to read this!

Comment: you can't use `home_url` in the second parameter of `add_rewrite_rule`, the second parameter ***always*** takes the form `index.php?queryvar=value&etc....` with matches inserted, just like the examples in the official WP developer docs for `add_rewrite_rules`. Rewrite rules don't map one URL to another URL, they only _map_ pretty URLs to ugly URLs of the form `index.php...etc`, they are not like apache rewrite rules

Comment: Thanks for your comment, read the comment by Alira in the dev docs which is not correct. Have fixed it and seems to be working correctly:

 public static function rewrite_rules() {
  add_rewrite_rule(
   'resources/([^/]*)',
   'index.php/resources/?language=$matches[1]',
   'top'
  );
 }

Comment: Actually, in this case $matches[1] did not assign the value to the query var, using $1 the trick:

  add_rewrite_rule(
   'resources/([^/]*)',
   'index.php/resources/?language=$1',
   'top'
  );

Comment: that's not a valid rewrite rule either, the `/resources/` part is not ok, if you want to replace `/resources/?languages=foo` with `/resources/foo` then you need to look up the query variables that `/resources` uses and include those in your new URL rewrite too. Rewrite rules is not a way to map arbitrary URLs on to other arbitrary URLs, the result has to be `index.php?var=value&othervar=othervalue&etc...`, anything else will cause issues